# Fingerprint scanner in codename one

Tags: codenameone, android-fingerprint-api

Question: 1
I want to use fingerprint scanner in codename one. Can anybody tell me is it available in codename one or not? If yes, how to use and if no, then how can I code it in codename one ?

Question: 2
How to get the maximum device info in codename one like android version, mobile model, or other stuff ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No. Fingerprint scanning isn't available at this time.

You can use native interfaces to integrate native device functionality check out [this quick video](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) and the [advanced section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) in the developer guide.

Device information is available in `Display.getProperty()` as well as some other methods in that class. Notice that if you get things such as UDID you will get a permission prompt.